# How to add items to a list from mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the code to for model:

```
public class CMBCategory
    {
        public int CatID { get; set; }
        public string CatName { get; set; }
        public List<Product_desc> productDesc { get; set; }
    }
    public class Product_desc
    {
        public int PructID { get; set; }
        public string prodName { get; set; }
    }
```

I need the result like a tree where we can not say the depth of the tree. Is it possible to create a tree  like structure like below using the above definition:

```
       photobook
           |________Redbook
                       |________Wedding
                                   |________Hindu
                                   |________Christian
                       |_________Baptism
```

Comment: If you want to generate a tree view like thing, you need have a `parentID` which is the immediate parent and unique ID to your object. Then you can create a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes **it is possible**, But maintain just one class which can construct a tree in a **Generic** solution rather than tight coupling the data. Below is an example.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID{ get; set; }
    public string ItemName{ get; set; }
    public List<Item> ChildItems{ get; set; }
}
```

As you can see we can have one generic Class called **Item** each item will have a ID, Name, List of Item which in turn will have ID, Name, List of Items and so on..

You need to have a track saying the root level is `Category` then second level can be `products` and third `sub products` etc etc.